# Как разбить строку на массив

Tags: php

Приветсвую. Есть у меня такая строка

`title=hello+world&name=name&phone=777&email=mail@mail.ru&city=city&message=msg`

И нужно разделить на ячейки массива, чтобы можно было работать с каждым параметром. 
Например, `$text['phone']`, и я получу `777`.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = array();

$line = 'title=hello+world&name=name&phone=777&email=mail@mail.ru&city=city&message=msg';

$ar = explode("&",$line);

foreach($ar as $arr){
    $lin = explode("=",$arr);
    $result[$lin[0]] = $lin[1]; 
}
print_r($result);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [title] => hello+world
    [name] => name
    [phone] => 777
    [email] => mail@mail.ru
    [city] => city
    [message] => msg
)
```

[explode_php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php)

Comment: на любом &amp; умрет, к сожалению

Comment: да я уже понял. Второй ответ то что надо

Answer (score 5):

Вам поможет функция **[parse_str](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-str.php)**

> parse_str — Разбирает строку в
> переменные

```
$query = "title=hello+world&name=name&phone=777&email=mail@mail.ru&city=city&message=msg";
parse_str($query, $text);
echo $text['phone']; // 777
```